# order y-axis of geom_tile plot by variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using geom_tile to visualize random draws

Generate data:

```
set.seed(1)
df= crossing(sim=1:10,part= 1:10)
df$result = sample(c(1,0),size = nrow(df), replace=T)
df = df %>% 
  group_by(sim)%>%
  # find out how many successful (1) pilots there were in the first 4 participants
  summarize(good_pilots = sum(result[1:4])) %>% 
  arrange(good_pilots) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  # add this back into full dataframe
  full_join(df) 
# plot data
plot = ggplot(df, aes( y=factor(sim), x=part)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = factor(result)), colour = "black", 
              show.legend = T)+

  scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightgrey", "darkblue"))+# c(0,1)
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(size = 2),
              plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.2)),
              axis.text = element_blank(),
              axis.title = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks = element_blank(),
              legend.title = element_blank(),
              legend.position = "right")+ theme_classic()+ coord_fixed(ratio=1)
```

This results in:

[image: Unsorted X axis plot]

What I actually want is the y axis to be ordered by the # of blue (ie 1's) in the first four columns of the block (which is calculated in `good_pilots`).

I tried `scale_y_discrete` but that cannot be what is intended:

```
plot + scale_y_discrete(limits=df$sim[order(df$good_pilots)])
```

resulting in: 
[image: weird looking plot]

From what I can tell it seems like the ordering worked correctly, but using scale_y_discrete caused the plot to be messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reorder` here

```
ggplot(df, aes(y = reorder(sim, good_pilots), x = part)) +
  ...
```

[image]